# Android: How to detect collision between two circles

Tags: android, collision-detection, geometry

I have drawn multiple circles of varying sizes and positions to a canvas, but I need to detect collisions between them.

```
public void run() {         
            while(Run){
                if(!sHold.getSurface().isValid())
                    continue;

                c[0][cnum].r++;
                canvas = sHold.lockCanvas();
                canvas.drawRGB(02, 02, 150);
                Paint white = new Paint();
                white.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                if(c[0][cnum].x != 0 && c[0][cnum].y != 0)
                    canvas.drawCircle(c[0][cnum].x, c[0][cnum].y, c[0][cnum].r, white);
                if(cnum!=0)
                    for(int i=0; i<cnum; i++)
                        canvas.drawCircle(c[1][i].x, c[1][i].y, c[1][i].r, white);
                sHold.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                if(((c[0][cnum].x - c[0][cnum].r)<0)||((c[0][cnum].y-c[0][cnum].r)<0)||((c[0][cnum].y+c[0][cnum].r)>height)||((c[0][cnum].x+c[0][cnum].r>width))){
                    c[1][cnum].x = c[0][cnum].x;
                    c[1][cnum].y = c[0][cnum].y;
                    c[1][cnum].r = c[0][cnum].r;
                    broken = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't do that on render phases.

When processing the logics you should check if circles intersects as described:

v1 = center of circle1
v2 = center of circle2

intersects = v1 - v2 < circle1radius + circle2radius

Answer (score 2):

This Link is pretty useful!

[Circle-Circle Collisions](http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/when-worlds-collide-simulating-circle-circle-collisions--gamedev-769)

It's very detailed and didatic

---

At the bottom of that page there are another links, to even more detailed stuff!

---

I used the Distance Between Centers method  ---
[Circles](https://cdn.tutsplus.com/active/uploads/legacy/tuts/393_qtCollisionDetection123/assets/circles_distance.png)

By measuring the distance between each center you can say if they are colliding.
The distance should never be more then the sum of the 2 radius.

Here's what I did:

```
private boolean checkDrawContains(ShapeDrawable newHole) 
{
    long newCenterX = newHole.getBounds().left + (newHole.getBounds().width()/2); //Get the center of my shapes
    long newCenterY = newHole.getBounds().top + (newHole.getBounds().height()/2);

    for(ShapeDrawable hole: mHoles) // I was storing the circles in an ArrayList
    { 
        long centerX = hole.getBounds().left + (hole.getBounds().width()/2); //Get the center of my shapes
        long centerY = hole.getBounds().top + (hole.getBounds().height()/2);
        long x = centerX - newCenterX;
        long y = centerY - newCenterY;
        long aux = (long) ((Math.pow(Math.abs(x),2)) + (Math.pow(Math.abs(y),2))); //Pythagoras the hard way :P
        long distance = (long) Math.sqrt(aux);
        long sRads = (newHole.getBounds().width()/2) + (hole.getBounds().width()/2);

        if(distance <=  sRads ) {
            return true;  //Is Colliding!
        }
    }
    return false; // Is not Colliding!
}
```

Comment: Can you further explain what the answer was that you found by reading that link? We want to try and have all information available in the post to answer the question, to make it more useful to future readers of the post.

Comment: Just did it! Thx for the tip